# Laravel RateLimiter/throttle increasing decay minutes

Tags: laravel, authentication, throttling, laravel-sanctum, laravel-fortify

In Laravel you can throttle certain requests. For example you can throttle your login requests by max 5 attempts per minute via middleware or a RateLimiter:

```
    RateLimiter::for('login', function (Request $request) {
        return (new Limit('login', '5', 1))
            ->by($request->email.$request->ip());
    });
```

In this code example, the `'5'` means the max amount of requests per minute, and the `1` means the decay minutes (every time the limit has been reached, the user will be locked out for 1 minute).

However, how do you increase the `decayMinutes` everytime the limit has been reached? For example, how would you double this amount each time?

Comment: make a new `Limit` class with the behavior that you want

Comment: Thanks @N69S for your reply. I was thinking about implementing that, but Laravel does not provide this out of the box?

Comment: I'm looking for the same behaviour. Any luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Info: I'm using **Breeze** with **Laravel 8**, which installs `app\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest`. This file is where I make the changes.

There were two important lines of code in order to customise the Laravel Breeze attempts and decay time. If you just want to hunt them out:

**Attempts**

```
RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts($this->throttleKey(), 5)
```

**Decay time**

```
RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());
```

`RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts` (you can see) takes a number as its second argument (above `5`) this is how many attempts someone is allowed.

`RateLimiter::hit` takes a second argument not shown, I was able to up mine to 5 minutes by adding it in:

```
RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey(), 300);
```